# Router won't re-offer DHCP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, dhcp, wireless-access-point

Wondering if this "as designed" or a bug in my netgear router.
I have an AP connected to the router (via EoP)
If i connect to the router SSID, get an IP then disconnect and connect to the AP SSID I can't get an IP. I've tried numerous AP's

Running TCPDUMP on the AP I see that the router responds to the DHCP Discover with an ARP request for the IP it previously issued....

Is this normal?

```
10:44:45.086801 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 52143, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
        0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 24:e3:14:1f:47:1d (oui Unknown), length 300, xid 0xdb47d999, secs 2, Flags [none] (0x
    0000)
              Client-Ethernet-Address 24:e3:14:1f:47:1d (oui Unknown)
              Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
                Magic Cookie 0x63825363
                DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
                Parameter-Request Option 55, length 7:
                  Subnet-Mask, Classless-Static-Route, Default-Gateway, Domain-Name-Server
                  Domain-Name, Option 119, Option 252
                MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1500
                Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether 24:e3:14:1f:47:1d
                Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 7776000
                Hostname Option 12, length 11: "Adams-Phone"
                END Option 255, length 0
                PAD Option 0, length 0, occurs 15
10:44:45.107653 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.0.3 tell 192.168.0.1, length 46
```

Comment: Yes, but the arp request isn't the problem... The router is getting a dhcp request from a MAC it already knows but on a different interface. So it's checking to see if that IP's in use before sending a DHCP Offer. Is it getting a response? If not, it should give the offer. Most home routers were not designed with the intention of having another AP connected... What specific router and AP are you using?

Comment: There is no response to the ARP, so an Offer should be sent. I've tried both an OpenWrt AP and a Buffalo AP. It doesn't seem like unintended use is the issue, it seems like protocols are incorrectly implemented.

Comment: Hmm... so multiple routers and multiple APs exhibit the same problem, they all can't have the protocols implemented incorrectly... what is the constant, the device? And by "EoP" in your original question doesit mean Ethernet over Power, what if you temporarily connect the AP with just a patch cable, does it work?

Comment: The NetGear router is the constant. Its the device I'm having issues with. I've tried to connect multiple AP's to it. I haven't tried a patch direct to the router... will do that, but the EoP adapters shouldn't be filtering